# Ubuntu 19.04 | Wi-Fi randomly disconnects then reconnects

Tags: drivers, wireless, 19.04, disconnect

I don't have a problem on either Windows 10 with this adapter. And it isn't a problem with my other devices either as the router isn't the problem.

Comment: Could you please provide *some* details of what is happening? How often it happens, if it is happening at regular intervals, what you tried to solve it etc.

Comment: I have the same issue using a Dell XPS 9370

Answer (score 0):

Probably not related, but thought I'd share by findings. I have a Netgear R6400 router, and I recently switched it to serve two SSIDs, one of them acting as a guest network. Once I turned the guest network off, my Ubuntu laptop started working again with no problems. This [article](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-disconnecting.html.en) is what drove me to try disabling it. I'm using a Dell XPS 2017 13 inch.

I suspect the Netgear was struggling to keep up with the device, and Ubuntu is a bit more sensitive to unreliable WIFI, as opposed to other versions/ other operating systems.

Hope it helps